# Can a finite state machine work with persistence without breaking the FSM encapsulation?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, persistence

Say we have a (UK) Traffic Light simulation app and a class **TrafficLight** has an associated finite state machine defined as:-

```
*  -->  RED  -->  RED_AMBER  -->  GREEN  -->  AMBER  -->  RED  --> ...
(repeat until the proverbial cows make an appearance )
```

On construction **TrafficLight**'s state is RED
Some kind of time trigger causes a state change.

In the app there may be some code like ( removing any code that takes away from point ) ...

```
TrafficLight trafficLightsAtBigJunction = new TrafficLight();  // state = RED
trafficLightsAtBigJunction.setState( TrafficLightState.RED_AMBER );
trafficLightsAtBigJunction.setState( TrafficLightState.GREEN );
trafficLightsAtBigJunction.setState( TrafficLightState.AMBER );
trafficLightsAtBigJunction.setState( TrafficLightState.RED );
trafficLightsAtBigJunction.setState( TrafficLightState.RED_AMBER );
:
:
:
```

The crux is, using the state pattern to implement the state machine, if we do

```
TrafficLight trafficLightsAtBigJunction = new TrafficLight();  // state = RED
trafficLightsAtBigJunction.setState( TrafficLightState.GREEN ); // Exception!!!!!
```

an exception is thrown ( by our design ) because it's an illegal state move. That's what we want. Everything is good with the world.

However if we then persist the traffic light and it happens to be at state = AMBER say then there appears to be a problem. When our user comes back 3 days later to watch the awesome traffic light simulation it is restored from the current state in some ( who cares ) persistent store.

**How do we get the traffic light instance to be in state AMBER without breaking the encapsulation that the state pattern provides here?**

There appears to be 2 choices:-
   (1) Create a new instance and run through the relevant states
   (2) Provide a **special method** to set the state to whatever we want that, by convention, is only used after reading from some persistence store. e.g.

```
trafficLight.setStateAfterReadingFromPersistanceSource( AMBER );
```

Issue with (1) as I see it is that there may very well be side effects I don't want when running through the states, plus the logic could be quite complex depending on the state machine

Issue with (2) is obviously it only works by convention so could introduce a bug without knowing when incorrectly used. More importantly it pretty much breaks all your nice pattern encapsulating which is what you wanted in the first place.

The question is persistence technology agnostic - same issue with ORM, Files, serialisation etc

I'm assuming there is a solution here but I can't think of one myself and my googling skills have not been sufficient.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a state machine by representing states and transitions as objects is certainly possible, but those objects require initialization (which appears to be your problem) and take the precious RAM.

However, there is also a completely different way of implementing state machines as pure code. This has so many advantages that I would never go back to the "state machine as data" method.

For a specific example, the DDJ article "UML Statecharts at $10.99" at http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/uml-statecharts-at-1099/188101799 shows exactly how to implement a Pedestrian LIght CONtrolled (PELICAN) crossing as a hierarchical state machine.

This example is coded in C for a low-end microcontroller. If you are interested in C++ implementation, you can take a look at the open source QP/C++ framework available from SourceForge.net at https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpc/files/QP_C%2B%2B/

Comment: I like the approach. Do you maybe have any pointers on how that approach would look like, if the state needs to be persisted?

Comment: Persisting a state is in general a complex problem, because you need to preserve not only the state of the internal state machine, but also the internal values of other attributes ("extended state variables"). A very interesting approach to persisting state generically is called "Event Sourcing" (you might want to google for this term). Event Sourcing will work with the state machine implementation I described in the post.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you want two ways to manipulate the state:

1) Transition from this state to another state, performing all side effects of this transition, throwing exception if illegal, etc

2) Set the machine directly to a state/set of internal values. Do nothing else.

You should persist everything that describes the FSM's internal state and have two methods, one that does the former, one that does the latter.

The latter will be used when setting up or when unpersisting. It's also much simpler to code since it'll just be transferring values into variables without worrying about what else needs to happen.

The former will be used during simulation.

Comment: Yeah so I guess that's a more succinct way of putting my question. There appears to be a dichotomy, as far as I see it. You have your "normal" encapsulated flow, but need some kind of "get out" because of persistence dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach may just be to pass the initial state as a constructor parameter - it's only your convention that the system starts with all lights as red.

Another approach would be to make the function which pulls data from the store a friend or member ( depending whether you're using operator>> to read it or something else ). This gives you the option to either transition to a state as per your example, or read an initial state from a store. There isn't much ambiguity as to what is happening, and it's up to the FSM to pull its state and whatever else it needs to and from the store when persisting.

Comment: Sorry, yes, on the constructor I did mean to include that as part of the options. I would bracket that with the special method to be used only when constructing from saved state. Similar disadvantage that it allows bugs to creep in elsewhere in code that has ability to create TrafficLights. On the RED as convention I do agree that is arguably true, but I choose the simplified case just to illustrate my point. What I meant to be clear about was that there IS a defined starting state, flow and end as defined by the FSM. Persistence seems to get in the way of it.

Comment: @AndyBoyle if something has the ability to create something, it generally has full control. Perhaps you want an environment builder and a simulator - the FSM implements a transition interface which the simulator sees, allowing it to perform state transitions, but the environment creates the concrete object which it can serialise or inflate.

Answer (score 1):

For the short answer I agree with Pete that, in this simplistic example, you can pass it as 
a constructor arg.

But I honestly think the entire design is flawed.  I would think this should be modeled using the standard State design pattern.  Something like this:

```
class TrafficLight 
{
   private TrafficLightState _lightState;

   TrafficLight(initialState)
   {
      // utilize lookup table or factory-method to assign _lightState with  the correct TrafficLightState subclass
   }

   // UI can use this to identify/render the appropriate color
   Color getColorCode()
   {
      return _lightState.getColorCode();
   }

   // UI uses this to know when to signal the next light change (each color can have different duration)
   int getDuration()
   {
      return _lightState.getDuration();
   }

   // assuming the UI has a timer that is set based on the current light's duration
   void changeLight()
   {
      TrafficLightState nextState = _lightState.onChangeLight();
      _lightState = nextState;
   }

}

abstract class TrafficLightState
{
   abstract Color getColorCode()
   abstract TrafficLightState onChangeLight()
   abstract int getDuration()
}


class RedLight : TrafficLightState
{

   Color getColorCode()
   {
      return Color.Red;
   }

   TrafficLightState  onChangeLight()
   {
      return new RedAmberLight();
   }

   int getDuration() 
   {
      return 30;
   }
}

class RedAmberLight : TrafficLightState
{

   Color getColorCode()
   {
      return Color.Orange;
   }

   TrafficLightState  onChangeLight()
   {
      return new GreenLight();
   }

   int getDuration() 
   {
      return 10;
   }
}

class GreenLight: TrafficLightState
{

   Color getColorCode()
   {
      return Color.Green;
   }

   TrafficLightState  onChangeLight()
   {
      return new AmberLight();
   }

   int getDuration() 
   {
      return 25;
   }
}

class AmberLight: TrafficLightState
{

   Color getColorCode()
   {
      return Color.Yellow;
   }

   TrafficLightState  onChangeLight()
   {
      return new RedLight();
   }

   int getDuration() 
   {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

State machines should not have an explicitly-exposed "change state" method that is used to transition in normal operations.  Instead, think of them as having stimuli that allow the state machine to transition its own state.  In this example, the stimuli was very simple but normally you'd have a bank of possible inputs that can cause a state transition.  But with proper encapsulation, the caller need not be overly aware of the details.

Comment: Interesting points. I don't disagree on the whole and the suggested implementation is solid. But I guess my question is perhaps more theoretical in the sense that I don't think it matters  whether or not it's the UI, some client or internal code that ends up moving the FSM to it's desired state. The thrust is that there is still the 2 choices to either allow a direct setting "somehow" or run through the states potentially having side effects. I do take your point that the client should be abstracted from the internal state changes themselves but "something" needs to move them to desired state

Comment: In that case, I don't think their can be a single answer because it depends on what the state machine is implementing.  For something like traffic lights you can jump to a state, sure.  But I've used state machines to deal with, for example, a tcp/ip protocol and you could not jump to the receive-response state without having entered the sending-request state.